# ¿Cómo se listan todos los milestones de todos los repositorios de github de un usuario u organización?

Tags: github

Actualmente puedo entrar a los milestones de los repositorios uno a uno poniendo por ejemplo en la URL:

- https://github.com/codenautas/dialog-promise/milestones ó
- https://github.com/codenautas/backend-plus/milestones

pero [codenautas](https://github.com/codenautas) tiene una gran cantidad de proyectos, varios de los cuales tienen milestones.

Lo que pregunto es ¿**cuál es la manera de listar todos los milestones** que existen en [codenautas](https://github.com/codenautas) o en cualquier otra organización o usuario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta respuesta está basada en SO en inglés https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40271837/how-to-list-all-milestones-in-a-github-user-or-organization

Con la API los Milestones solo pueden ser listados por repositorio, por lo tanto no se puede pedir los milestones de toda la organización. La manera posible (de costo `O(n2)`) es hacerlo uno por uno iterando en cada organización e ir concatenando la información obtenida en cada iteración.

Se puede mitigar de algún modo el costo de uso de las API utilizando requerimientos condiciones gracias al tag `ETag` que viene en las respuestas del API y reenviando el valor recibido en el parámetro `If-None-Match header—if`. Así, si no hubo cambios, el api contesta 304 y esa llamada no cuenta en el límite periódico de llamadas a la API.